# When exactly to use php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, setup, bin-magento, command

There are lots of situations in which I change some files in my module in the developer mode but the changes didn't take place in frontend until I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Just wanted to know when should we run `setup:upgrade` command and what's the purpose of it in Magento 2?

It's just so strange for me, because every time I'm doing some changes, they won't be visible until after I run the setup:upgrade command. Even if I delete the var/cache, it's still not visible. Does anyone know any reason for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you enabled one or more modules, then you will need to run `magento setup:upgrade` to update the database schema.

By default, `magento setup:upgrade` clears compiled code and the cache. Typically, you use `magento setup:upgrade` to update components and each component can require different compiled classes.

```
magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

The optional `--keep-generated` option should be used only in limited circumstances by experienced system integrators. `--keep-generated` should never be used in a development environment.

Improper use of this optional parameter can cause errors during code execution.

### UPDATE (07/10/17)

As the topic creator asked me:

> But its just so strange for me, because everytime I'm doing some
>   changes, they won't be visible until after I run the setup:upgrade
>   command. Even if I delete the var/cache, its still not visible. Do you
>   know any reason for this?

`var/cache` in Magento 2 is not enough to makes changes visible like Magento 1. In Magento 2, you will need to clears `var/generation` (and `var/di` if you compiled code) after you made changes inside your code, especially whenever you change something inside the constructor.

You will also need to clear `var/view_preprocessed` if you change something inside your template file (.phtml)

The rest will goes to `var/cache` and `var/full_page_cache`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your answer. But its just so strange for me, because everytime I'm doing some changes, they won't be visible until after I run the setup:upgrade command. Even if I delete the var/cache, its still not visible. Do you know any reason for this?

Comment: Maybe you're not clearing enough directories. Maybe the `setup:upgrade` command is clearing them for you. Look at [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html) for reference. I am assuming your module is enabled; if not, that also causes issues.

Comment: @MichelGokan I updated the answer.

Comment: Do we need to run the setup:upgrade after disabling extensions?

Comment: @Webninja Yes, we do.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable modules, change modules version you will need to run `magento setup:upgrade` to update the database schema.

In other cases when you add new data in your class constructors, you need to run `magento setup:upgrade` because it clear var/generation folder.
To understand it, remove write and read permissions for `var` folder and run the command `magento setup:upgrade`

You will get an error message like this 
`Command line user does not have read and write permissions on var/generation directory.  Please address this issue before using Magento command line.`

meaning that this command is clearing folder var/generation. 
If you want to get your changes without executing `magento setup:upgrade` command, you need to clear these three folders

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*`